# How can I make Mix run only specific tests from my suite of tests?

Tags: elixir

How can I make Mix run only specific tests from my suite of tests?

When running `mix test` all tests are executed

Answer (score 117, accepted):

There are 5 ways to run only specific tests with Elixir

1. run a single file with `mix test path_to_your_tests/your_test_file.exs`
   This will run all test defined in `your_test_file.exs`
2. run a specific test from a specific test file by adding a colon and the line number of that test
   for example `mix test path_to_your_tests/your_test_file.exs:12` will run the test at line 12 of 
   `your_test_file.exs`
3. define a tag to exclude on your test methods

   ```
   defmodule MyTests do
       @tag disabled: true
       test "some test" do
           #testtesttest
       end
   end
   ```

   on the command line execute your tests like this
   `mix test --exclude disabled`
4. define a tag to include on your test methods

   ```
   defmodule MyTests do
       @tag mustexec: true
       test "some test" do
           #testtesttest
       end
   end
   ```

   on the command line execute your tests like this
   `mix test --only mustexec`
5. Generally exclude some tagged tests by adding this to your `test/test_helper.exs`file
   `ExUnit.configure exclude: [disabled: true]`

**Warning:**
Mix has an `--include` directive. This directive is **NOT** the same as the `--only` directive. Include is used to break the general configuration (exclusion) from the `test/test_helper.exs`file described under 4).

For some reason googling for `elixir mix include tests`or the like never shows up on my search results therefore I have written this entry and its answer. For more info, see [the Mix documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html).

Comment: And you can also do: `mix test path/to/file:line` and it will run the test in that file, at that line.

Comment: bear in mind that this does NOT work if you are working on an umbrella application. In that case you'll have to use something like: `mix cmd --app your_app mix test path_to_your_tests/your_test_file.exs:12`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `mix test` to run certain test files, just rename them. `mix test` matches on any file ending with `_test.ex` or `_test.exs` so all you have to do is rename those files that you don't want to run to something else that does not match, like `_test_off.ex`.

`controller_test.exs` -> `controller_test_off.exs`